# How can I create some images with known entropy

Tags: java, image, entropy

I wrote a function in java, which calculates the entropy of a 2D image based on its gray-histogram.
Now I want to check if it works correctly or not. How can I create an image with known entropy?

```
public static int[] computeHistogram2D(Grid2D grid, int bins, int width, int heigth) {

    int[] histo = new int[bins];
    double[] histof = new double[bins];
    float val = 0;
    float max = -Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    //maxVal:  -3.4028235E38 .. minVal:  3.4028235E38
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < heigth; j++) {
                val = grid.getAtIndex(i, j);
                if (val > max) {
                    max = val;
                }
                if (val < min) {
                    min = val;
                }
    }
}

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < heigth; j++) {
                val = grid.getAtIndex(i, j);
            int b = (int)val;
                histo[b]++;
                histof[b]++;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("maxValgrid2D:  " +max + "   minValGrid2D:  " + min);
    VisualizationUtil.createPlot(histof, "histogram2D", "intensity", "count").show();
    return histo;

}
static double computeEntropy2D(Grid2D grid,  int width, int height) {
System.out.println("width:" +width + "height " + height);
double[] entropyArray = new double[40];
                double entropy = 0.0;
                int bins = 40;
                int sizeX = width;
                int sizeY = height;
                int sizeZ = 1 ;
                int size = sizeX * sizeY * sizeZ; //Total pixels
                System.out.println("size:  " + size);
                int[] histo = computeHistogram2D(grid, bins, sizeX, sizeY);

                for (int i = 0; i < bins; i++) {
                    double val = (double) histo[i] / (double) size; //Normalized Histogram

                    entropy = entropy + (-(val * Math.log (val + 0.00001)));
                    entropyArray[i] = entropy;

                    //System.out.println("maxValgrid2D:  " +max + "   minValGrid2D:  " + min);

                }
                VisualizationUtil.createPlot(entropyArray, "entPlot", "tX", "Entropy").show();
        System.out.println("entropy2D:   " + entropy);
                return entropy;
            }
```

I'm working on my master thesis, when I wrote this my superwiser said you have to check your codes with some image with known entropy, You have to create image with known Entropy ... I searched a lot but couldn't find any thing too help me with that...

Comment: It depends on how you measure entropy.

Comment: @Jorge.V Can you please explain more! Or should I copy the codes in the question?

Comment: Matlab has the similar function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html. You can use it for tests.

Comment: Posting code would definatelly help. What I meant is, to know if your calculation works, you need to know a formula that can be applied to processing the image and give you a value. Do you have this formula?

Comment: @Jorge.V I posted my codes as well and more about my problem below ... I know the formula of entropy ... but as I explain I need to create an image with known Entropy!

Comment: Well the problem is you can't really "know" the entropy for your image, it depends on how you measure it. See [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235270/entropy-of-an-image) . What you can do if you've a formula of your own is see if it's consistant with its results. If you are using a popular standard-ish way of measuring it (and hence interpreting it) you can probably find around a generator. Are you using a known model?

Comment: @Jorge.V Thanks, But  I've read that already ... i didn't get exactly what do you mean by model... I used image gradient and then Shanon entropy based on that gradient..